# How do I maintain a Bazel cache with GitHub Actions?

Tags: github-actions, bazel

I build code on GitHub Actions using Bazel, which is preinstalled. Bazel has the ability to cache steps on the file-system to skip work on subsequent builds.

But how can I save this cache in GitHub Actions for use in subsequent workflow runs?

Comment: You can cache things in general with https://github.com/actions/cache. Depending on what specific actions you're using, there may be other ways to configure caching.

Comment: ... which is what I am asking

Comment: Read e.g. https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows. If you still have a question, please [edit] to clarify the specific problem with applying this in your case (if you are using other actions, for example, what are they?)

Comment: Bazel caches are not like those of some other build-systems because they contain a content-addressable store that can be grown from all workflows, rather than partitioned by a key so my question is specific to Bazel and GitHub Actions.

Comment: Have you seen how tensorflow does it? They use a GCP bucket for caching: https://github.com/tensorflow/io/pull/1287

Comment: Thanks @rethab I would like to use the 5GB cache that GitHub provide though (if possible!)

Answer (score 2):

Use the cache action, e.g.:

```
jobs:
  build_and_test_ubuntu:
    name: Linux Ubuntu 20.04 Bazel build <GCC 9.3.0>
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Mount bazel cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: "/home/runner/.cache/bazel"
        key: bazel

    - name: Build and Test
      run: |
        bazel build //...
        bazel test //...
```

Comment: Apparently it's not quite simple, see discussion on https://github.com/actions/cache/pull/575/files re. what an appropriate `key` is...